# Update a bash variable in the while loop test from within the loop?

Tags: loops, while-loop, global-variables

I have a very-long-oneliner that outputs `true` or `false` whose I want to wait to be `true` to process further.
My `until` loop works OK this way:

```
var=$(very-long|oneliner)
until [[ $var = true ]]; do sleep 5
var=$(very-long|oneliner); done
```

But when I want get it lighter:

```
var=$(very-long|oneliner)
until [[ $var = true ]]; do sleep 5
var=$var; done
```

it fails when initial $var is `false` because `var` after `do` is never updated as I hoped. I learned this is because at some point the loop goes in a sub shell, then `var` is no more the output of the oneliner, but get stuck to false. Is there a way to do it ? Maybe the first line would be `declare -g var=$(very-long|oneliner)` (I never used this and am afraid it spreads I don't know where in the system),or `declare -x var=$(very-long|oneliner)`?

Thanks in advance for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify. Make sure your one-liner exits with a valid code.

```
until very-long|oneliner
do sleep 5
done
```

as long as `very-long|oneliner` returns `0` then true, it'll work.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I don't understand: the end of the oneliner is awk that searches a specific line in a file and ouputs the last word, false or true, then it always exits with 0. Even when I drive it where it won't find true or false... OK, I got it work this way, with the help of `grep` to get a reliable 0|1 exit code. I wasn't able with awk only + 1 week reading the excellent gawk manual : `until [[ \`$verylongcurl/command.org|awk -v DID=$DevID '$0~DID,/}/ {if ($0~/online/) print}'|grep "\"online\": true,"\` ]]; do sleep 5; done`